# How is PHP installed when you use yum or apt-get

Tags: php, yum

I always get this weird questions about how stuff works behind the scenes. I know how to compile php from source, and I know that if you compile it from source and forget to add a module/library you need to re-compile php to add it. However, if you install php lets say using yum, and then you want to add another extension, you just need to install that extension. For example, today I was working on a recently installed Fedora 18 machine, and php was missing the DOM library, which is weird, since that library is enabled by default. It seems like yum installs php with that extension disabled. Anyway, since it was missing, I had to do this:

```
sudo yum install php-xml
```

And that solved the problem, but it made me wonder, how is the installation process in this case? Is php re compiled? and if so, how does it remember all the other extensions that may have been added before? Or is the xml extension installed separately and somehow linked into php?

I haven't found any info about this, and I'm really curious as to how it works.

Comment: there are magical 'yum' elves casting runes.

Comment: Ah, OK, no wonder I heard weird noises at night ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build extensions separately,  you don't have to rebuild your php every time you need to add a new extension, you just need to define the extensions that needs to be loaded under `[extensions]` in your `php.ini`.

When your building php you can specify which extensions you need to be statically (included) in the php binary vs which once you want as a shared library.

```
configure --enable-http=static --with-openssl=shared
// http extension will be included in PHP
// openssl extension will be compiled as separate DLL
```

Comment: I see. I didn't know you could do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you install php extension packages using a package manager like yum or apt-get, the repositories have the already compiled so extensions for the version of php that came with the system. For example, if you're on Ubuntu 12.04, and you do a apt-get install php-mysqlnd, it fetches the deb package from the repository which contains the pre-compiled mysqlnd.so and a default mysqlnd.ini. This works because the deb package has the compiled version according to the default dependencies that are installed for the 12.04 release. If some dependencies are missing, the precompiled deb packages are fetched for the same, thus eliminating the need for configuration and make. This make it a lot faster and easier. Almost plug and play!

Comment: Thanks. I was actually taking a look at the configuration files in php.d and it made some things clearer. I can see that each one includes its own module, and those modules are compiled as shared objects just as you pointed out. Thanks a lot for confirming that for me :D

Answer (score 0):

Yum connects to repositories of pre-compiled rpm's. Yum will download the rpm and its dependencies and install them.

Yum will use different repositories for different OS's. For example Fedora 18 has a different repostitory of pre-compiled rpms then Fedora 17 would have.

Yum is just a glorified dependency management system

Comment: I understand the part of the repositories, and dependencies, or at least I think I do. But that doesn't completely clarify my question of how those newly installed packages get linked to php. Maybe I'm missing something?